# Easy mathematical transformation {equation} (still having problems)

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

so in my syllabus the professor wrote

> $q = 500 / p - 4$

from which he deduced

> $p = 500 / q + 4$

I cannot arrive at the same p, especially because of the positive 4...

[image: Two of my worthless tries]

Comment: The lesson we can all learn from this is that when you're multiplying both sides by something, remember to multiply all of the terms! In the top box, you forgot to multiply the 4 by $p$; and in very last box you should have moved the term $-4p$ to the left-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

Your professor made a mistake. The last $p$ is missing:
$$
q p = 500 - 4p
$$
But I wonder if he made it on purpose, to show that it leads to a wrong result.

The last derivation seems also not correct
$$
\begin{align}
q p &= 500 - 4p \iff \\
p &= 500/q - 4p/q
\end{align}
$$

I would reverse $q(p)$ like this:
$$
\begin{align}
q &= (500/p) - 4 \iff \\
q + 4 &= 500 / p \iff \\
p &= 500 / (q + 4)
\end{align}
$$
The last step is only valid for $q+4 \ne 0 \iff q \ne -4$.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that your teacher make a mistake, let $p=1$, then $q=496$ from the first equation.

And we can easily see that with this choice of $q$, the RHS of the second equation is not an integer but $1$ is an integer.

Your teacher's answer would have been correct if he was solving $$q=\frac{500}{p-4}$$ instead.

As for your working, Matti has pointed out that you seems to have the consistent mistake of forgetting to multiply/divide certain terms.